# Как передать в VBA символы польского алфавита?

Tags: vba

В ячейке записан текст на польском: "dziękuję". Пытаюсь считать и отобразить значение
x = ActiveCell.Value
MsgBox (x)
Однако вместо символа "ę" выводится "e": "dziekuje". Как это исправить?

Comment: Вроде поддержки `unicode` в окнах нет. Если только пытаться конвертнуть как-то, но думаю может и не получиться. Хотя как альтернатива [вот](http://blog.nkadesign.com/2013/10/01/vba-unicode-strings-and-the-windows-api/) посмотрите, может поможет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант, применявшийся для пользовательских многоязычных форм. Вместо `MsgBox`  создать свое сообщение.

Создать форму (`Insert-UserForm`), на ней разместить `Label`, под надписью кнопка *OK* или 2-3 кнопки управления (*Да/Нет/Отмена*). Да чего угодно можно наворотить )

Вместо строки вывода `MsgBox` строку отображения формы:

```
Call UserForm1.Show
```

В модуле формы

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.Caption = "Очень страшное предупреждение"
    Label1.Caption = ActiveCell.Value
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

В заголовке вместо кириллической надписи можно разместить датское ругательство - тоже брать из ячейки :)